# axios.get returns error code 400, but then resolves correctly with code 200

Tags: node.js, axios, http-status-code-400, http-status-code-200

I am trying to make an axios call in my code to get a csv file and convert it to JSON.
I am able to make the call and conversion correctly when the code stands on its own, but when I change it to be called as a function from an external source, I get an error code 400 when the axios call is executed, but then I get a correct response with status 200 anyway.
This is the code I am executing as a test:

```
console.log('Test1');
getCSVUsers(usersurl, user, pass, CSVdelimiter)
    .then((usersjson) => {
        console.log(usersjson.users[0]);
    })
```

And the definition of the function:

```
//Dependencies
import axios from 'axios';
import csv from 'csvtojson';

const getCSVUsers = (url,user,pass,delimiter) => {
  console.log('Test3')
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Test4');
    let users = {}; //Creating JSON structure
    users.users = []; //Creating required array in users JSON.

    const options = { //Creating GET call credentials requirements
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic '+Buffer.from(`${user}:${pass}`).toString('base64')
        }
      }
      console.log('Test5');
        //Make API get call
        axios.get(url, options) //Making the call
        .then(response => { //Getting the response
          console.log('response.status'); 
          csv({ 
            delimiter: delimiter, //Defining the CSV delimiter
            trim:true
          })
            .fromString(response.data) //Processing CSV from response
            .then(function(jsonArrayObj){ //putting result in object
              users.users = jsonArrayObj; //putting object in json array
              resolve(users);
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('TestErr');
          console.error(err);
        });
  });
}

export {getCSVUsers}
```

The console returns the following:

```
Test1
Test3
Test4
Test5
Response Error:Error: Request failed with status code 400
200
{User1 stats are returned correctly}
```

I tried making the function async and adding "await", but that didn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Could it be because you're doing axios.get and sending 'post' in the options?

Comment: I don't think so. I tried changing it to a POST call but then it created other errors.
Also I am using this exact same function in a different code (minus the CSV conversion part) and it works correctly.

Comment: @sava128 I just checked, to be safe. If I change the header to "Get" I still get the same issue, if I change the axios call to POST I get a completely different error 401 message.
But as I said, the code works correctly elsewhere anyway.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? can you debug the request from there? also, try removing the method option if you're not really doing a POST request here

Comment: @sava128 I tried removing the method, but got the same issue.
I've never done a server debugging before. I run it on my own machine via Visual Studio Code, so I assume I have access to the server, but I don't know how to debug it.